# How to get clicked boxes on Django multiplechoicefield in JS

Tags: django

I'm working on an E-Mail preview tool and wanted to display a formatted version of a Django multiplechoicefield based on the selected boxes using Javascript. I'm trying to do something to the effect of:

```
$('#email_preview').click(function (click) {
    event.preventDefault();
    my_js_function("{{ form.data.modchoicfield }}");
});
```

I've also tried:

```
$('#email_preview').click(function (click) {
    event.preventDefault();
    my_js_function($('#id_modchoicfield').val());
});
```

Since it is a preview I don't want to send the E-Mail, just display what it would look like based on their input. Neither of these seem to do anything as the output is just blank. I tested the function with a static string and it works great so I know it is the way I'm trying to access the field values. Any help would be awesome and if you need any more details let me know, thanks!

EDIT:
Here is a more in depth idea as to how everything operates on the form and template level.

email form:

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    # Using dummy value for specific_incident because queryset must be initialized on ModelChoiceField

OPTIONS = (
    ("Empty",),
)

contacts = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked": ""}), choices=OPTIONS)

def __init__(self, associated_emails):
    super(EmailForm, self).__init__()
    self.fields['contacts'].choices = tuple([(contact['id'],
                                              str(contact['name']) + " " + str(contact['email']()))
                                             for contact in associated_emails])
```

Template:

```
<form action={% url "email.views.send_email"%} method="post" class='col-sm-5'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_field form.contacts %}
        <button type="submit" id="email_preview" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in" %} Preview Email
        </button>
    {% endbuttons %}

    <div id="formatted_email" class="hidden"></div>
</form>

<script>
    $('#email_preview').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        copyTextToClipboard($('#id_contacts').val());
    });
</script>
```

And the odd thing is this works perfectly fine in the exact same template in the exact same script tag:

```
{
    'mfield': $('#id_mfield').val(), //modelchoicefield in same form
    'another_mfield': $('#id_another_mfield').val(), //modelchoicefield in same form
    'cfield': $('#id_cfield').val(), //charfield in same form
}
```

Comment: Your first attempt definitely won't work, because a form doesn't know what's the up-to-date value the form has. Is there anything in the console for your second approach? Also make sure you type the id name correctly.

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks, I wasn't sure if it would or wouldn't because I know  you can get the value for a charfield with $('#cfield').val() and since that wasn't working I gave .data a shot. As for name, I'm 99.9999% sure, I copied it straight from the html tag and check probably about 20 times by now lol.

Comment: Your form got submitted because you didn't call `event.preventDefault()` correctly. You should have `event` as a function parameter not `click`.

Comment: @ShangWang I saw that and fixed it but it is still getting submitted for some reason. I did make a typo on the question though, it is a multiplechoicefield not modelchoicefield. Just updated.

Comment: What's the type for your `email_preview` button? You might need to show us your form as well. Worst case you can move the button to the out side of the form so it doesn't related to the form at all.

Comment: It's of type submit, I switched to type button as well but I got the same result. What is also odd is getting modelchoicefield values and charfield values in the exact same way work great. I'm using django bootstrap for the form. I just updated my question to give you a better idea as to how everything is implemented.

Comment: Type button and type submit are the same thing in a form. I can't try it personally so it's kinda helpless from here. As I suggested worst case you can move the `email_preview` button outside of your form, then make sure your jquery picks up the right DOM component.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#email_preview').click(function (event) { // <-- it should be 'event' btw
   event.preventDefault();
   my_js_function("{{ form.modchoicfield }}"); // <-- no need for 'data'
});
```

Comment: I had tried that but it submits the form for some reason when I try passing "{{ form.modchoicfield }}". That's why I was trying to use form.data.modchoicfield.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#email_preview').click(function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    my_js_function($('#id_modchoicfield').val()); 
 });
```